# Replacing part of div in my preview with html entites

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my script I can preview my out put by clicking on my preview button.

In side my pre tags if there is a open `<div>` and close `</div>` found with `<` and `>`  how can I just replace it with the html entities I have tried

```
$('.preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
```

But because there are br tags in there it replaces the ones around br also which I do not want. I only just want to replace the ones around the open and close div's in side my pre tag.

> **Question:** how can I just replace it with the html entities `&lt;` and
>   `&gt;` only round the open and close **divs**

Codepen Example [Here](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/amxzax)

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
    var editor = $('#question').val(); 
    $('.preview').html(editor.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
    $('.preview pre').next('br').remove();

    if ($('.preview').find("pre").length > 0){ 
        var str = $('.preview pre').html(); 
        $(".preview pre div").replaceWith("&lt;div&gt;");
        //$('.preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").next('div'));  
        $('.preview pre').html(str);    
        $('pre').each(function(i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block); 
        });
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need to pass only the br tag? 
You can try to match all of the lt and gt symbols and then compare two symbols before > and two symbols after <. If it's match with br then pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have make a for loop for detect only `div` element and remove all `<br>`. It's a bit ugly but work fine.

```js
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
 var editor = $('#question').val(); 
 $('.preview').html(editor.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
 $('.preview pre').next('br').remove();

 if ($('.preview').find("pre").length > 0){ 
  var $str = $('.preview pre');
        var pre = $str.html();
        $str.html("");
        pre = pre.replace(/<br>/g,"\n")
        for(t=0;t<pre.length;t++){
          if(pre.substr(t,1) == "<" && pre.substr(t+1,3) == "div"){
            $str.html($str.html() + pre.substr(0,t).replace(/</g, '&lt;'))
          }else if(pre.substr(t,1) == "<" && pre.substr(t+1,4) == "/div"){
            $str.html($str.html() + pre.substr(0,t+5).replace(/</g, '&lt;'))
          }
          if(pre.substr(t,1) == ">" && pre.substr(t-3,3) == "div"){
            $str.html($str.html() + pre.substr(t,1).replace(/>/g, '&gt;'))
          }
        }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
}


.panel {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: #4d525b;
    border-color: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title"></h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Title</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Question</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<textarea name="question" id="question"  class="form-control" rows="10">
Hello this is some code
  
<pre>
  <div class="">
  </div>
</pre>
</textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2"></label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div class="preview"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="btn-group text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="preview-question" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```